# Ruby Gem Version Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm not able to script/console to my rails app after upgrading from ubuntu 9.10 to 10.04

```
# gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

aaronh-chronic (0.3.9)
abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.5, 2.3.10, 2.3.5)
actionpack (3.0.5, 3.0.3, 2.3.10, 2.3.5)
activemerchant (1.12.0, 1.9.0)
activemodel (3.0.5, 3.0.3, 3.0.1)
activerecord (3.0.5, 2.3.11, 2.3.10, 2.3.5)
activeresource (3.0.5, 2.3.10, 2.3.5)
activesupport (3.0.5, 3.0.3, 3.0.1, 2.3.11, 2.3.10, 2.3.5)
addressable (2.2.4)
after_commit (1.0.8)
ambethia-smtp-tls (1.1.2)
arel (2.0.9, 1.0.1)
authlogic (2.1.6)
braintree (2.8.0, 2.6.1)
builder (3.0.0, 2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.10)
cancan (1.4.0)
capistrano (2.5.19)
crack (0.1.8)
daemon_controller (0.2.6, 0.2.5)
erubis (2.6.6)
exception_notification (2.3.3.0)
faraday (0.5.7)
faraday_middleware (0.3.2)
fastthread (1.0.7)
file-tail (1.0.5)
hashie (1.0.0, 0.4.0)
highline (1.6.1)
hodel_3000_compliant_logger (0.1.0)
hoe (2.9.1, 2.6.2)
hominid (3.0.2, 2.2.0)
hpricot (0.8.4, 0.8.3)
httparty (0.7.4, 0.6.1)
i18n (0.5.0, 0.4.2)
json (1.5.1, 1.4.6)
json_pure (1.5.1, 1.4.6)
justinfrench-formtastic (0.2.4)
mail (2.2.15, 2.2.13)
mime-types (1.16)
minitest (2.0.2, 1.6.0)
mislav-will_paginate (2.3.11)
multi_json (0.0.5, 0.0.4)
multi_xml (0.2.1)
multipart-post (1.1.0)
mysql (2.8.1)
net-scp (1.0.4)
net-sftp (2.0.5)
net-ssh (2.1.3, 2.0.23)
net-ssh-gateway (1.0.1)
oauth (0.4.4, 0.4.3)
oink (0.1.2)
passenger (3.0.4, 3.0.0)
polyglot (0.3.1)
rack (1.2.1, 1.1.0, 1.0.1)
rack-mount (0.6.13)
rack-test (0.5.7)
rails (2.3.10)
railties (3.0.5)
rake (0.8.7)
rdoc (3.5.3, 2.5.8)
riddle (1.2.2, 1.1.0)
rubyforge (2.0.4)
rubygems-update (1.5.2)
searchlogic (2.5.3, 2.4.27)
simple_oauth (0.1.4)
spruz (0.2.5, 0.1.5)
super_exception_notifier (3.0.13)
test-unit (2.2.0, 1.2.3)
thinking-sphinx (2.0.2, 1.3.20)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.9)
twitter (1.1.2, 0.9.12)
tzinfo (0.3.24, 0.3.23)
whenever (0.6.6, 0.6.2)

# gem -v
1.5.2

# rails -v
Rails 2.3.10

# script/console 
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.10)
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:779:in `report_activate_error':Gem::LoadError: RubyGem version error: rails(2.3.4 not = 2.3.10)

/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/init.rb:264:in `require':LoadError: no such file to load -- console_app
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/init.rb:264:in `require':LoadError: no such file to load -- console_with_helpers
```

Any help is appreciated!

-Anshu

Comment: have you tried gem update --system?

Answer (score 4):

Your `config/environment.rb` probably specifies `RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.4'` which is why you're getting the `rails(2.3.4 not = 2.3.10)` error message.

Either `gem install rails -v=2.3.4`, or change your `environment.rb` file to the correct version of Rails

Comment: My environment file has 2.3.10 as version

Answer (score 0):

The log suggests that there's a conflict between RubyGems and Rails. Try to reinstall rails gem.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you upgraded your system, I would suggest removing all gems (I recently followed [this post](http://geekystuff.net/2009/1/14/remove-all-ruby-gems) to do so), as some natively compiled ones won't work in the new OS.
2. Check that running `ruby -v` from your shell shows that you are using version 1.9.1, since it is looking for the gem for that Ruby version.
3. Check if there is an explicit Rails version number specified in `config/environment.rb`, or in your `Gemfile` if you have one.

Comment: I removed all my gems, and did a fresh install. One thing I noticed though is that my ruby version is 1.9.2 while rubygems is still trying to look at 1.9.1 root@dev-recmend:/home/recmend/recmend/featureblogr# script/console 
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.10)
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:779:in `report_activate_error':Gem::LoadError: RubyGem version error: rails(2.3.4 not = 2.3.10)
# gem -v
1.5.2
# ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [i686-linux]
# rails -v
Rails 2.3.10

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Ubuntu use rvm, it will save you a lot of trouble and allow you to safely play around with versions and dependencies....

slothistype

Answer (score 0):

Same problem faced by me. So In before installation of any Gem and ruby, here I used rvm ie ruby version manager, which separates the different version of ruby from creating conflicts.

[Click Here For RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/)